# Konstruktionen mit Modalverben in Vergangenheit

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure

Was ist der Unterschied?

1. > Ich muss mich zur Prüfung vorbereitet haben

   und

   > Ich habe mich zur Prüfung vorbereiten müssen
2. > Er soll seine Frau umgebracht haben.

   das habe ich in einer Zeitung gesehen

   > Er hat seine Frau umbringen sollen.

   Gibt es einen Unterschied, wenn ich diesen Satz so formuliere?
3. > Er soll sein Handy nicht verloren haben.
   >
   > Er hat sein Handy nicht verlieren sollen.

Kann man auch bei allen diesen Fällen Modalverben in Präteritum verwenden?
Wie zum Beispiel:

> Ich musste mich zur Prüfung vorbereitet haben
>
> Er sollte seine Frau umgebracht haben.
>
> Er soll sein Handy nicht verloren haben

Comment: Hi! Herzlich willkommen auf der German Language Seite. Du hast einige gewaltige Missverständnisse hinsichtlich der Äquivalenz der von Dir angebotenen Alternativen. Sie sind weder irgendwie direkt austauschbar, noch in der von Dir vorgeschlagenen Form generalisierbar, sondern beschreiben völlig unterschiedliche Sachverhalte. Es ist leider nicht so einfach wie Du vielleicht denken magst, und es benötigt ein (dickes) Grammatik-Buch all diese zu erklären. Du hast bestimmt eines, und ich möchte Dir raten dieses noch einmal zu konsultieren um den Satzbau zu analysieren.

Comment: Die gröbsten (vermutlich typographischen) Fehler habe ich mir erlaubt zu korrigieren

Answer (score 1):

> Ich muss mich zur Prüfung *vorbereitet haben*.
>
> Er sollte seine Frau *umgebracht haben*.

Die Infinitivgruppen (kursiv) sind vorzeitig. Es handelt sich um Infinitiv Perfekt Aktiv. D.h. die Handlung findet vor der Zeitebene des Hauptsatzes statt.

Im ersten Satz heißt das konkret, dass meine Vorbereitungen vor der Prüfung abschließen muss. Im zweiten Satz würde das so verstanden werden, dass er seine Frau mittlerweile umgebracht haben muss, da ja die Handlung schon passiert sein muss, denn der Hauptsatz steht im Präteritum.

> Er soll sein Handy nicht *verloren haben*.
>
> Er soll seine Frau *umgebracht haben*.

Auch hier haben wir wieder Inf. Perf. Akt. Genau das gleiche wie zuvor gilt.

Diese Sätze klingen übrigens nach einer direkten Redewiedergabe. In einem Text könnte ich also z.B. „Er hat sein Handy nicht verloren“ so wiedergeben.

> Er *hat* seine Frau umbringen *sollen*.
>
> Er *hat* sein Handy nicht verlieren *sollen*.
>
> Ich *habe* mich zur Prüfung vorbereiten *müssen*.

Hier sind die Hauptsätze im Perfekt (Prädikate sind kursiv).

Der erste Satz bedeutet, dass er seine Frau umbringen musste (Vergangenheit). Hier gehören „hat“ und „sollen“ zusammen. Das Modalverb ist also im Perfekt.

Umbringen ist Inf. Prä. Aktiv, daraus folgt Gleichzeitigkeit. Wir können das so verstehen, dass er allgemein (zu der Zeit, die durch das Perfekt im Kontext ausgedrückt wird) seine Frau umbringen musste.

Das gleiche gilt für die beiden anderen Sätze. Zur Erzählzeit durfte er sein Handy nicht verlieren und zur Erzählzeit musste ich mich auf die Prüfung vorbereiten.

Ob der Hauptsatz im Perfekt oder Präteritum steht ist eigentlich unerheblich. Der einzige Unterschied ist, dass Perfekt natürlich besonders in der gesprochenen Sprache verwendet wird.